# Product of column with input value of user in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

So for example my dataset is that

```
col1<-rep(c("a","b","c","d"),3)
col2<-rep(c(1:4),3)
col3<-rep(c("l","m","n"),4)
col4<-rep(c(9:12),3)
df<-data.table(col1,col2,col3,col4)
```

I am trying to create a new datatable where the result is the product of each column with the value given from the user and then sum them to one like

```
final=l*value1+m*value2
```

The problem is how to create the product value of each column with the value.

Hera is my app

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("value",
                "value"),
      selectInput("choice",
                  "choice",unique(df$col3)),
      actionButton("update", "Update"),actionButton("calculation", "calculation")
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput("table"),dataTableOutput("table2"),dataTableOutput("combined")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  Data<- reactive({
    if(input$choice == "NULL") {data <- df}
    else {data <- subset(df, col1 == input$choice)}

    data
  })

  output$table<- renderDataTable(Data())



  dat<-c()

  table2 <- eventReactive(input$update, {
    if(!is.null(input$value) && input$update>0 ){
      newrow = data.table(value= input$value,choice=input$choice)
      dat <<- rbind(dat, newrow)
    }
    dat
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)

  output$table2<- renderDataTable(table2())

data_wide <-dcast( df, value.var=  "col2", col1~col3)
new<-c()


alldata<-eventReactive(input$calculation, {
  for (i in table2()$choice)
  { new<-c(new,i)}
  data_new<-na.omit(subset(data_wide, select=c("col1",new)))

})
output$combined <-  DT::renderDataTable( alldata())


}
# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

table2 result will be

```
value choice
 2      l
 3      m
```

and if the user selects column l and value 2 and column m and value 3 the result output wil be the final column

```
value1 l value2 m final
 2     2   3    3  5  
 2     4   6    3  10
 2     6   9    3  15
 2     8  12    3  20
```

I added the rows below this but this error occurs
Warning: Error in *: non-numeric argument to binary operator

```
  product<-eventReactive(input$calculation, {
    for(j in 2:ncol(alldata())){
      set(alldata, i = NULL, j = j, value = alldata()[[j]] * table2()$value[j-1])
    }
    alldata()
  })
  output$product <-  DT::renderDataTable( product())

}
# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I don't understand from your description what you are trying to calculate the the code isn't very clear. Can you be more specific about the desired output for certain inputs?

Comment: But where is `m` defined? Where does `2*m` "go" exactly?

Comment: @MrFlick I tried to make it more clear I hope it helps

Comment: I have to agree with @MrFlick, its hard to understand. But i think a dataframe stored within `reactiveValues()` (instead the global variable) should solve it.

Comment: It looks like your `final` only has one number. If you select column l and value 2 and column m and value 3, then the result is 5. I you select values 4 and 6, then you get 10. That does not seem very useful.

Comment: Give us the complete output for a single case with actual selections. We can see what `df` is. Chose `column1`, `value1`, `column2`,`value2`, then show us what you expect the entire `table1`, `table2` and `combined` data tables to look like. I know it is work, but you need to make your spec complete or you cannot get to a solution. And don't get discouraged. Learning to think precisely enought to program this kind of thing takes a lot of practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think I finally got it.

The following changes needed to be made - some cosmetic - but those helped a lot:

- Moved the `dat` into a `reactiveValues` as BigDataScientist suggested so we could get rid of the nasty `<<-` assignments.
- Changed all the table output to `verbatimPrintOutput` so more data could fit on the screen, all that `renderDataTable` functionality is not needed here.
- Added outputs for `df` and `data_wide`. A mention of `data_wide` and how it is calculated in the problem description would have helped.
- Added the calculation you were trying to do. Having the data in front of you makes it easier to see what needs to be done.
- Added a `Clear` button so you don't have to restart the program when you mess up.
- Added a `numericInput` for the value instead of a `textInput`
- Possibly a few other small things I have forgotten.

Here is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(reshape2)
library(data.table)

col1<-rep(c("a","b","c","d"),3)
col2<-rep(c(1:4),3)
col3<-rep(c("l","m","n"),4)
col4<-rep(c(9:12),3)
df<-data.table(col1,col2,col3,col4)

ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Column Product Calculations"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("value", "Value",value=2,min=-10,max=10),
      selectInput("choice", "choice",unique(df$col3)),
      actionButton("clear", "Clear"),
      actionButton("update", "Update"),
      actionButton("calculation", "calculation")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      h4("df"),verbatimTextOutput("dfout"),
      h4("table"),verbatimTextOutput("table"),
      h4("table2"),verbatimTextOutput("table2"),
      h4("data_wide"),verbatimTextOutput("data_wide"),
      h4("combined"),verbatimTextOutput("combined")
    )  
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  Data<- reactive({

    if(input$choice == "NULL") {data <- df}
    else {data <- subset(df, col3 == input$choice)}

    data
  })

  output$table<- renderPrint(Data())

  rv <- reactiveValues(dat=NULL)

  observeEvent(input$clear,{rv$dat<-NULL})

  table2 <- eventReactive(input$update, {
    if(!is.null(input$value) && input$update>0 ){
      newrow = data.table(value= input$value,choice=input$choice)
      rv$dat <- rbind(rv$dat, newrow)
    }
    rv$dat
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)

  output$dfout <- renderPrint(df)
  output$table2<- renderPrint(table2())

  data_wide <-dcast( df, value.var=  "col2", col1~col3) 

  alldata<-eventReactive(input$calculation, {
    t2 <- table2()
    new <- t2$choice
    data_new<-na.omit(subset(data_wide, select=c("col1",new)))
    data_new$final <- 0
    for (i in 1:nrow(t2)){
      c <- t2$choice[i]
      v <- t2$value[i]
      print(sprintf("c:%s  v:%1.f",c,v))
      data_new$final <- data_new$final + v*data_new[[c]]
    }
    data_new
  })
  output$data_wide <-  renderPrint( print(data_wide) )
  output$combined <-  renderPrint( alldata() )
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And here is a screen shot:

[image]

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept the answer now and an up vote is always nice.

Comment: There are other ways to do that final multiplication, but unrolling it like that has advantages of clarity.